# zabbix monitoring VMware vSphere CPU Usage value isn't correct compare with the vCenter website

Tags: vmware, zabbix

Recently, I build up the Zabbix(Zabbix 4.4.0.) for monitoring the VMware vSphere hosts' CPU Usage via vCenter SDK, linked to the default template(Template VM VMware Hypervisor), but the data from lastest data of one vSphere CPU Usage( CPU usage, vmware.hv.cpu.usage[{$URL},{HOST.HOST}] ) isn't correct compare with vCenter - monitoring - Advance(similar, but not precise), attached the following pic.
Does anyone knows about it, thanks.

[CPU Usage - Template VM VMware Hypervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xg8.png)

[CPU Usage - Zabbix LatestData Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwf7j.png)

[CPU Usage - Zabbix LatestData Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVZQG.png)

[CPU Usage - VMware vCenter website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46B8Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix, by default, polls data from vCenter every 1 min, change that to 30 seconds or less to get more precise data. Also, you can try to poll CPU info using vmware.hv.perfcounter key in Zabbix and VMware performance counters.

Here you can find step-by-step instruction on how to change polling interval and how to add new metrics using vmware.hv.perfcounter key:

https://bestmonitoringtools.com/vmware-monitoring-with-zabbix-esxi-vcenter-vm-vsphere/